# ionic 3 - How to receive local notification when app is closed

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have try tutorial in here https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/ for schedule delayed notification.It is working when app is running. But i'm unable to receive delayed notification when app is closed. Is possible to receive delayed notification when app is closed. If yes, please help me.

Thank's in advance..

Comment: onbackbutton press call this code **this.backgroundmode.moveTobackground**. It will move the app in background and you can easily receive local notifications. It is working in my case.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it is not working for me. What I'm looking for is we need to send a local notification at particular time even though application is not opened. Is there any way like that. If yes, please help me

Comment: Use some kind of subscriber that execute the code after every 15 seconds or the time delay you want like this **Observable.timer(17000).first().subscribe(() => this.updateValues());** and use your code in updateValues()

Comment: Sorry, I already schedule notification with particular time. I'm not getting local notifications when app is not running. If we use this in our code, when is called I mean when the app is closed or killed

Comment: So you want to receive notifications when the app is closed or killed right?? For that use some kind of push notifications or move the app into the background than you can use the local notifications. But if you want to receive local notifications once the app is closed. This is not possible according to my opinion.

Comment: Yes, but I need to make it using local Notifications. Actually what is my task is "I need to send reminder like local notification at particular time" when app is closed also?. Is it possible?

Comment: I also tried this but it is not possible because local notification plugin code will execute after the app initialization or once the app is in ready state. I made a workaround by moving the app in backkground when user presses the back button so according to user app is closed and my code executes.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Background mode plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode/) to prevent the app from going to sleep while in background.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, I done the same but not working. Still I'm not able to receive delayed local notification when app is closed.

Comment: For anyone wandering into this as I did. backgroundMode is not working on android for Ionic 3 / Angular 5. When the app is in background it just stop and when brought back in foreground it is restarted. https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/issues/346